# How to reuse the same Watermark TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a WatermarkTextBox that inherits TextBox and I have x:Name="TestASearch" which will be called in the listview to display 
the search returned from the method textboxsearch_TextChanged.

```
        <controls:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="TestASearch"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="10,61,0,10" SelectAllOnGotFocus="True"  Background="White"
                TextChanged="textboxsearch_TextChanged">
                <controls:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
                    <TextBlock  FontStyle="Italic"   Text="Enter search text…" Width="116"/>
                </controls:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
```

WatermarkTextBox class

```
    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(WatermarkTextBox)));
    }
```

Now I want to use the same concept except that I want a different x:Name =TestBSearch and wanted to use TextChanged="textboxsearch_TextChanged"

```
            <controls:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="TestBSearch"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="10,61,0,10" SelectAllOnGotFocus="True"  Background="White"
                TextChanged="textboxsearch_TextChanged">
                <controls:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
                    <TextBlock  FontStyle="Italic"   Text="Enter search text…" Width="116"/>
                </controls:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
            </controls:WatermarkTextBox>
```

When I try this I get error "PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'WatermarkTextBox'." How can I reuse the same code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata should be set in a static constructor:

```
static WatermarkTextBox()
{
    FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(WatermarkTextBox)));
}
```

Comment: BTW Why is it so important to change it from public to static? besides the error

Comment: A static constructor is only called once.  As you had it in a normal constructor, and created two instances of the class, you were overriding the metadata for that class twice - which can't be done.

Comment: Thanks Lee ...I got it now.